# iPad: Is there a frame like the GroupBox in C#?

Tags: ipad, border, frame

I'm new to iPhone/iPad development. I'm looking for a way to visually groups some controls just like the GroupBox in C#. I know it doesn't make much sense in iPhone due to limited space, but my app is for iPad only and customer wish to see that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. You could simulate it with a Label and a `UIView` with a little bit of custom drawing (just to draw the border, and an inner shadow if you'd like).